# searching without clicking a button

Tags: php, textbox

I need help. I want to input a letter or letters into a textbox then I need all the names that have those letters appear in the table without clicking any button, how can I do that?

this is my code

```
<html>

    <body>
Name:    <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2">
        <div id="table-scroll">
        <table cellpadding="8" cellspacing="5" id="fo">
         <thead>
           <tr>
           <th>Patient Number</th>
           <th>Patient Name</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
           <tbody cellpadding="8">
            <?php 
             include( 'connect.php');
              $term=$ _POST[ "text2"];
              $sql="SELECT * FROM tblnpatient WHERE pname LIKE '%$term%'" ;
              $result=m ysql_query($sql); 
              while($row=m ysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
                echo '<tr class="record">'; 
                echo '<td>'.$row[ 'pname']. '</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row[ 'pnum']. '</td>'; 
              } 
        ?>
 </tbody>

</html>
```

Comment: Use jQuery Ajax to get new values from server. Or pass `$term` as `$_GET` parameter using `$('#myTable').load(url + ' #myTable > *', function(){})`

Comment: You're probably best off retrieving all the items with PHP, then using JavaScript to filter the ones that shown in the table, I stead of making tonnes of new requests for every search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a jQuery autocomplete feature.

Take a look at this article: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

This is how you implement it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        <script>
            $(function() {
            var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
            ];
            $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
            });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ui-widget">
            <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
            <input id="tags">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

so for your needs, you need to query your database, select all the values you want to "auto suggest/complete" and output it into the js array.

Comment: can i ask u how to get the value from the database?